# Sumar horarios entre si

Tags: php, laravel

tengo un problema, estoy intentando sumar dos horarios entre si, pero me da error

```
$horarioactual = "02:00:00";
$horarionuevo = "01:00:00";
$calculo = date("H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual + $horarionuevo));
dd($calculo );
```

Error: **A non-numeric value encountered**

Como puedo resolverlo?

Comment: estas sumando dos cadenas primero, y luego haciendo el strtotime. creo que deberia ser: `$calculo = date("H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual) + date("H:i:s", strtotime($horarionuevo));`

Comment: @Jakala intenté de esa forma pero sigue le mismo error A non-numeric value encountered

Comment: prueba esta: `$calculo = date("H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual) + strtotime($horarionuevo));`. acabo de comprobarla en un sandbox de php.

Answer (score 3):

Tu código no da error. Pero tiene un problema de lógica

Esto `$horarioactual + $horarionuevo` es `=3`

Por lo que el siguiente código no tiene sentido

```
$calculo = date("H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual + $horarionuevo)); //MAL
```

---

Podría tener más sentido

```
$calculo = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual) + strtotime($horarionuevo)); //También MAL
```

Pero tiene un problema:
*(en la fecha que escribo esto)*

`strtotime($horarioactual)`

- 1689656400 (en unix)
- "2023-07-18 02:00:00" (en fecha humanos)

y `strtotime($horarionuevo)`

- 1689652800 (en unix)
- "2023-07-18 01:00:00" (en fecha humanos)

Entonces sumar `1689656400 + 1689652800` da  un número muy grande y nos manda al año 2077

La solución es restar año/mes/dia actuales usando `strtotime('midnight')`

```
$calculo = date("H:i:s",strtotime($horarioactual) + strtotime($horarionuevo) - strtotime('midnight'));
```